# adding 12 hours to mysql current timestamp

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to filter my query data to only return items where `"Meeting Start"` is greater than `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ***but*** not later than 12 hours from the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Can I add 12 hours to the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP inline below in my query?

Current Working Query:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE [Room_ID] = '$field' AND [Meeting Start] > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY [Meeting Start] asc ";
```

Updated Try:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE [Room_ID] = '$field' AND [Meeting Start] > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND [Meeting Start] < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 12) ORDER BY [Meeting Start] asc ";
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`NOW() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR` should do the trick. `+12` is ambiguous. 12 seconds? minutes? days? years?

Comment: Interesting - Didn't know you could do this without a date/time function.

Comment: @nickb: Yeah, the `INTERVAL` keyword is a useful one :-P

Comment: doesn't seem to work with CREATE TABLE `Customer6` (
 `CreatedDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 4 HOUR)

Comment: try `DEFAULT TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 8, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`