# Php MySQL Update a field and wait 12 hours

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

Working with PHP and MySQL. Trying to figure out how to update a field in the Database when the person clicks the button, just adds +1 to the current value and only allowing them to click it/add +1 once every 12 hours.

What I have so far..

```
<p><h3 class="page-header">
     <?php _e('Title'); ?>
   </h3>
    <a href="Link" target="_TOP" class="btn btn-info btn-large"> 
     <?php _e('Button Text'); 
       $sql = "UPDATE `login_users` SET `MGV` = WHERE `MGV` = +1"; ?>
        &raquo;</a>
</p>
```

The Table I want to update is 'login_users' the field is 'MGV'.. I just want it to add +1 to the current and not allow another one for 12 hours. I have a Timestamp field as well, just no earthly idea how to go about adding a time limit before it will allow again.. Any help is much appreciated ^__^

Comment: log the time when the click, check the log before allowing again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Php script you should read the timestamp field from the database and verify it is more than 12 hours before the current timestamp. If it is so, then you can proceed with the update query you already have.

Lets say your timestamp in the datsbase is x, you should verify that
x+(60*60*12)<=time()
If this is true, you can update.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This has given me a lot of insight on how to check for the time ^__^ Now the issue just lies in updating the MGV field with +1 current value.

Comment: You can also read the current value stored in the database for the MGV field. You can use the same SELECT statement to read both MGV and timestamp. Then you can make an UPDATE where you just save the new timestamp and the value you just read +1.

Comment: Aight, I think I get what you are saying. Now I just gotta figure out where I am going wrong :3

Comment: Hey fun, do you use skype? I'd like to run a few variations of this by you without flooding this page :3

Answer (score 1):

Store `Current_Timestamp()` when they click the button.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `login_users` SET `MGV` = `MGV`+1 AND timestamp_field = Current_Timestamp() WHERE `USER_ID` = $user_id";
```

You can then check the next time using `NOW() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR` as described here: [adding 12 hours to mysql current timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070765/adding-12-hours-to-mysql-current-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JavaScript function to test this via AJAX, but if the user deactivates JavaScript? It should be on server-side.

Before you run that UPDATE SQL query, you should SELECT the row, test against the last_updated timestamp you got, and use something like this

```
if ( strtotime('-12 hours') < $query['last_updated_time'] )
// RUN SQL code here
else
// Show a error to user
```

I hope this answer is clear.